# TopAppBarScrollBehavior for scaffold TopAppBar not working when its NOT LazyColumn

Tags: android, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, scaffold

I am trying to use `TopAppBarScrollBehavior` for my `TopAppBar` inside `Scaffold`. BUT my content is NOT `LazyColumn`. It's a regular `Column` with a `scrollstate`.
Here is my code

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(backgroundColor),
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = "About",
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
                )
            },
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                containerColor = Color.Red,
                titleContentColor = Color.Black,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            navigationIcon = {
                Button(onClick = { }) {
                    Text(text = "B1")
                }
            }, actions = {
                Button(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(text = "B2")
                }
            },
            scrollBehavior = scrollBehaviour
        )
    },
    content = {
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it)
                .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        ) {
            // Header
            Text(
                text = "Header",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 30.dp)
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .semantics { heading() },
                fontSize = 26.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
            )

            //Many other components in between

            Text(
                text = "Some text",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, top = 38.dp)
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .semantics { heading() },
                fontSize = 21.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.black)
            )
        }
    }
)
```

the `TopAppBar` does not collapse or expand according to scrolling.
What changes do I need to make to `TopAppBar` to behave as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)):

> A scroll behavior is designed to work in conjunction with a scrolled content to change the top app bar appearance as the content scrolls.

Use:

```
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                //....
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                  //column content
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: I tried this but still I am not able to scroll the content. Am I missing anything or the code is outdated? I am using material3

Answer (score 0):

If your content is not a ScrollabeColumn or LazyColumn then you need to wrap your content in a ScrollableColumn for it to work

Make sure to use topAppBarScrollBehavior in the ScrollableColumn's modifier

Comment: I cannot use LazyColumn as it's not a list. And I do not think there is anything like ScrollabeColumn in Jetpack compose in Android

Comment: If you want to use topAppBarScrollBehavior with regular content and not a LazyColumn, then your regular content needs to be wrapped in a ScrollableColumn in order for topAppBarScrollBehavior to work.

Comment: It's important to note that TopAppBarScrollBehavior only works with a ScrollableColumn, so if your content is not a LazyColumn, you'll need to wrap it in a ScrollableColumn in order to use the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having trouble making a scrollable column work in the Scaffold content, you have to wrap your Scaffold content in a non-inline Composable (meaning a custom one which isn't Column/Row etc), ie:

```
@Composable
fun ScaffoldContent(
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    )
}
```

And then just pass it to Scaffold content:

```
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                //....
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        content = { innerPadding ->
            ScaffoldContent(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                  //column content
            }
        }
    )
```

This happens because Column is an inline Composable and it's overflow gets cut off.